# proc or function that will loop over each database in snowflake and list tables with empty rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone help find these zero row tables?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE checkrows()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$
function ExecuteNonQuery(querystring) {

 var out = '';

 cmd1 = {sqlText: select * from information_schema.tables where rows_count = 0;};

 stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);

 var rs;

 try{

     rs = stmt.execute();

     rs.next();

     out = "SUCCESS: " + rs.getColumnValue(0);

      }

      catch(err) {

      throw "ERROR: " + err.message.replace(/\n/g, " ");

      }enter code here

     return out;

    }
    
    $$;
```

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: There was "can someone help" question in the title, so yes. My cleanup removed that. I'll change the body to reflect the OP question.

Comment: Apart from the typo ROWS_COUNT vs ROW_COUNT, and did not loop through the resultset, what's wrong with the code above? I am a bit confused on the request on this.

Comment: loading is automated, so am looking for a procedure/function that can loop over the databases and return empty rows so i can create a task and schedule the task to call the proc every hour

Comment: It creates the proc but when I call the proc it returns one row in a test database that i created tables without a row, I think it's missing some arguments at the top in the braces near the proc name and i used different arguments then the proc did not cr.eate

Comment: It created but was returning error each time when i called the sp, i tried different arguments

Comment: GM Greg just tried it again, it created but when i called it, it came back with  db_gen table which is from snow flake default database and did not return an empty table i created without a row I called it with call FIND_EMPTY('.*');

Answer (score 1):

If you have a use case that it's okay to get row counts that are several minutes older than the last change (generally 15-90 minutes but up to 3 hours), you can simply run this:

```
select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."TABLES"
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and DELETED is null and ROW_COUNT = 0;
```

Edit: Since this needs to be automated, this SP will return a variant array with objects containing the db, schema, and table name of all tables with zero rows.

```
create or replace procedure FIND_EMPTY_TABLES(DATABASE_PATTERN string) -- Use .* for all databases in account. It will skip SNOWFLAKE and SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA
returns variant
language javascript
execute as owner
as
$$
class Account {constructor(databases){this.databases = databases;}}
class Database {constructor(name) {this.name = name;}}
class Query{constructor(statement){this.statement = statement;}}

var account = getDatabasesInAccount(DATABASE_PATTERN);
var out = [];

for (var i = 0; i < account.databases.length; i++) {
    out = out.concat(rsToJSON(getQuery(
       `select TABLE_NAME, TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_OWNER 
        from ${account.databases[i].name}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and ROW_COUNT = 0`)));
}

return out;

//------

function getQuery(sql){
    cmd1 = {sqlText: sql};
    var query = new Query(snowflake.createStatement(cmd1));
    query.resultSet = query.statement.execute();
    return query;
}

function executeSingleValueQuery(columnName, queryString) {
    cmd = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(columnName);
}

function getDatabasesInAccount(databasePattern){
    const SYSTEM_DB_NAMES = ["SNOWFLAKE", "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"];
    var db = executeSingleValueQuery("name", "show databases");
    var i = 0;
    var dbRS = getResultSet(`select DATABASE_NAME from "${db}".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES where rlike (DATABASE_NAME, '${databasePattern}');`);
    var databases = [];
    var db;
    while (dbRS.next()){
        db = new Database(dbRS.getColumnValue("DATABASE_NAME"));
        if (!SYSTEM_DB_NAMES.includes(db)) {
            databases.push(db);
        }
    }
    return new Account(databases);
}

function getResultSet(sql){
    let cmd  = {sqlText: sql};
    let stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    let rs   = stmt.execute();
    return rs;
}

function rsToJSON(query) {
    var i;
    var row = {};
    var table = [];
    while (query.resultSet.next()) {
        for(col = 1; col <= query.statement.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            row[query.statement.getColumnName(col)] = query.resultSet.getColumnValue(col);
        }
        table.push(row);
    }
    return table;
}

$$;


call FIND_EMPTY_TABLES('.*');  -- .* is the RegExp pattern that tell it to check all databases except built-in ones.
```

Comment: What's wrong with INFORMATION_SCHEMA? Why did you suggest ACCOUNT_USAGE while INFORMATION_SCHEMA has no latency?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA only covers a single DB, which is presumably why the OP was looking for a stored procedure to collect across DBs. If latency is not acceptable, an SP or SQL generator would be the way to go. Want to understand the use case first.

Comment: loading is automated, so am looking for a procedure/function that can loop over the databases and return empty rows so i can create a task and schedule the task to call the proc every hour

Comment: Okay, so since you need to check it through automation here's an SP that will return a variant array with the db, schema, and table of each zero row table.

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES` view returns all databases the current role has access to. `SHOW DATABASES` can return more. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/databases

Answer (score 0):

Dirty and quick option adding to gregs excellent answer ... obviously if you like the results add 'create or replace zero_row_count_base_tables as ...' .... set it to re-create the view maybe weekly/daily then run the view when you want.

```
SELECT
'  SELECT  TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME  from UTIL_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_TYPE = \'BASE TABLE\'  AND ROW_COUNT > 0 '
UNION 
SELECT  concat( 'UNION SELECT  TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME  
FROM ', DATABASES.DATABASE_NAME,'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = \'BASE TABLE\'  AND ROW_COUNT > 0   ')
FROM  UTIL_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES
```

Comment: Please can anyone help the proc above is not working