# Please I am trying to create a proc or function that will loop over databases in snowflake and return all tables with empty rows

Tags: function, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was helped with this code in my earlier post but it still did not work, instead it returns the default snowflake table like 7 times on one call.

```
  create or replace procedure FIND_EMPTY_TABLES(DATABASE_PATTERN string) 
    returns variant
    language javascript`
    execute as owner
    as
    $$
    class Account {constructor(databases){this.databases = databases;}}
    class Database {constructor(name) {this.name = name;}}
    class Query{constructor(statement){this.statement = statement;}}
    var account = getDatabasesInAccount(DATABASE_PATTERN);
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < account.databases.length; i++) {
        out = out.concat(rsToJSON(getQuery(
           `select TABLE_NAME, TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_OWNER,ROW_COUNT 
            from ${account.databases[i].name}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and ROW_COUNT = 0`)));
    }
    return out;
    //------
    function getQuery(sql){
        cmd1 = {sqlText: sql};
        var query = new Query(snowflake.createStatement(cmd1));
        query.resultSet = query.statement.execute();
        return query;
    }
    function executeSingleValueQuery(columnName, queryString) {
        cmd = {sqlText: queryString};
        stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
        var rs;
        rs = stmt.execute();
        rs.next();
        return rs.getColumnValue(columnName);
    }
    function getDatabasesInAccount(databasePattern){
        const SYSTEM_DB_NAMES = ["SNOWFLAKE", "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"];
        var db = executeSingleValueQuery("name", "show databases");
        var i = 0;
        var dbRS = getResultSet(`select DATABASE_NAME from "${db}".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES 
    where rlike (DATABASE_NAME, '${databasePattern}');`);
        var databases = [];
        var db;
        while (dbRS.next()){
            db = new Database(dbRS.getColumnValue("DATABASE_NAME"));
            if (!SYSTEM_DB_NAMES.includes(db)) {
                databases.push(db);
            }
        }
        return new Account(databases);
    }
    function getResultSet(sql){
        let cmd  = {sqlText: sql};
        let stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
        let rs   = stmt.execute();
        return rs;
    }
      
    function rsToJSON(query) {
        var i;
        var row = {};
        var table = [];
        while (query.resultSet.next()) {
            for(col = 1; col <= query.statement.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                row[query.statement.getColumnName(col)] = query.resultSet.getColumnValue(col);
            }
            table.push(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
    $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is read the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES view where ROW_COUNT = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `ACCOUNT_USAGE` view `TABLES`:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME 
FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."TABLES" 
WHERE ROW_COUNT = 0
```

But you should be aware that there could be some latency.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [proc or function that will loop over each database in snowflake and list tables with empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144129/proc-or-function-that-will-loop-over-each-database-in-snowflake-and-list-tables/69144416#69144416) and I wrote a stored procedure there to do this.

Comment: Greg it did not work, it kept on returning only one table out 100's of tables and when i tried it on another acct, it was returning dbgen only ...you can test it too

Comment: The dbgen one is odd - there's something strange in the naming of the DB for that one like a hidden character or something. The other issue, not reporting other tables that are empty, should not be happening. If you want to jump on a Zoom to fix it you can email me using the standard email conventions for Snowflake.